# Property Accessors on List<T> in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have a property called Fruits which contains a comma delimited string in the form "apples,bananases,peaches"

I want to make a list in the same class which makes the Fruits property easier to manipulate. Accessors won't work as they are not supported on lists or so it seems.

Basically i want a property called FruitList which auto populates based on the Fruits Property and when adding items or manipulating the FruitList it should auto populate the fruits property.

I need the Fruits Property for Entity framework.

Comment: `bananases` FTW! (It's just `bananas`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invert the logic:

```
List<string> fruitsList = new List<string>();
public List<string> FruitsList
{
    get
    {
        return fruitsList;
    }
}

public string Fruits
{
    get
    {
        return string.Join(',', fruitsList);
    }
    set
    {
        // Incomplete, does not handle null
        FruitsList.Clear();
        FruitsList.AddRange(value.Split(','));
    }
}
```

You don't need to worry about updating `Fruits` if `Fruits` is determined by looking at `FruitsList`. You mention that you need `Fruits` as a `string` property for Entity Framework, but EF does not care whether it is backed by a `string` field.

Answer (score 1):

The only realistic way to do this is to use a collection which can be observed for changes, and handle the event raised when it is changed, and update the property.

Something like [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms668604.aspx) would fit the bill.

example:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Fruits{get;set;}

    public IList<string> FruitList 
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new ObservableCollection<string>(Fruits.Split(','));
            list.CollectionChanged += (s,ea) => {
               var items = (IList<string>)s;
               Fruits = String.Join(",",items);
            };
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj= new MyObject(){ Fruits="Apple,Banana,Orange" };
var list = obj.FruitList;
list.Add("Satsuma");
list.Add("Grapes");
list.Remove("Apple");
Console.WriteLine(obj.Fruits); // Output: Banana,Orange,Satsuma,Grapes
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/KCT33825

Having seen the *concept* here work, it's worth noting that the above implementation is frought with a bit of danger. It creates a new `ObservableCollection` every time you call the `get` accessor on it, which could have some unintended consequences.

For example, if you add the following line just before my original `Console.WriteLine`:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj.FruitList == list);
```

It outputs `false` which might seem strange as you might (and notionally, should) expect `list` and `obj.FruitList` to point to the same list.

You can get round this by changing the implementation to create only ever 1 `ObservableCollection` and always returning that from the `get` accessor:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private string fruits;
    private ObservableCollection<string> fruitList;
    public string Fruits
    {
        get{ return this.fruits; }
        set
        {
            this.fruits = value;
            this.fruitList = CreateFruitList();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> CreateFruitList()
    {
        var list = new ObservableCollection<string>(this.fruits.Split(','));
        list.CollectionChanged += (s,ea) => {
           var items = (IList<string>)s;
           this.fruits = String.Join(",",items);
        };
        return list;
    }


    public IList<string> FruitList 
    {
        get
        {

            return fruitList;
        }
    }
}
```

Now all is right with the world again!

Comment: not a good solution, what if I do something like this (what *everyone* normally would do in C#): obj.FruitList.Add(..), obj.FruitList.Add(..)... every time a new instance of list created, bsolutely abnormal behaviour. So why, I suggested to use distinct methods, and not property in this case. Very confusional architecture.

Comment: @Tigran - did you read the update before posting that? I specifically described this case, and a minor enhancement to get around it.

Comment: @Tigran - also dont start getting pissy just because I downvoted your (wrong) answer! Be an adult.

Comment: it's not about pissy, casue the solution I proposed in *alternative* it a better, from **my point of view**, then creatiing all arround architecture around this. Immagine release your code to 10 developers in china, who didn't know anything about your API, imo CreateFruitList, FruitList,,, whatever is a source of confusion. Distinct method with declarative clear intention about what is going on, is a way better, in *this+ case.

Comment: `CreateFruitList` is **private**. How the HELL would anyone using this care (or even know) about it's existance. Learn to read. Sheesh, some people!

Comment: it was just an *example*. Creating all that stuff only to sync string with a list and list with a string is an overkill, just revise an architecture, there *for sure* has to be some other more simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

here's what you could do, create a proxy for your comma separated list:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Fruits {get;set;}

    public string [] FruitList {
        get { return Fruits.Split(new [] {','}); }
        //warning, the setter is dangerous
        set { Fruits = string.Join(',', value); }
    }
}
```

When I say the setter is dangerous, I only mean that if you change one element of the array, the Fruit won't be updated. It'll only be updated if you push a new array. If you need that behavior, consider implementing it using an ObservableCollection